# My window.scrolltop not working

Tags: javascript, salesforce, lightning

I am using `window.scroll` function, but `window.scrollTop` didn't return any value in lightning controller. Help me.

```
initialize : function(component, event, helper) {
            var isHidden = false
            var lastScrollTop = 0
            console.log('heyyyyyy');
            window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
                console.log('heyasasyyyyy');
                var scrollTop =  document.documentElement.scrollTop;
                var offset = scrollTop-lastScrollTop ;
                lastScrollTop = scrollTop ;
                console.log(scrollTop+'++++'+offset+'++++++'+lastScrollTop);
            });

        },
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo: 3rd row - latScrollTop instead of la**s**tScrollTop.

Fixed Code:

```
initialize : function(component, event, helper) {
            var isHidden = false
            var lastScrollTop = 0
            console.log('heyyyyyy');
            window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
                console.log('heyasasyyyyy');
                var scrollTop =  document.documentElement.scrollTop;
                var offset = scrollTop-lastScrollTop ;
                lastScrollTop = scrollTop ;
                console.log(scrollTop+'++++'+offset+'++++++'+lastScrollTop);
            });

        },
```